# Regularization term nurbs surface fitting

Tags: geometry, optimization, spline

When fitting b-spline curves $c(u)$ to points, it is usual to write a cost function such as:

$$
    \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( [(p_k-c(u))^T\cdot n_k]^2 \right)
$$

The function is then derived so as to express unknow control points $P_i$ and then solve for them.

Now when it turns to fitting a b-spline surface $s(u,v)$ to a points cloud, it is usual to see a cost function with several components, to both 1) stick to points $p_k$ and 2) get a smooth surface. 2) is called the regularization term. The cost function is given by:

$$
    \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( [(p_k-s(u,v))^T\cdot n_k]^2 \right) + \lambda \int \|\ddot{s}(u,v)\|^2dt
$$

Though I have not been able to find a paper or book where the surface fitting cost is derived, even the NURBS book does not mention it. I think I could find out how to derive component 1) on my own (extending the way things are done for the curves), but I have really no idea how to derive component 2).

Any idea? Any link to websites, books, or papers?

---------- EDIT -----------

$\ddot{s}(u,v)$ is not well defined and only "captures" that the regularization is aimed at mitigating the deformations of the resulting surface. A more accurate an widespread cost function is given by the **thin plate spline** method:

$$
    \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( [(p_k-s(u,v))^T\cdot n_k]^2 \right) + \lambda \iint \left[\left( \frac{\partial^2s}{\partial u^2}\right)^2 + 2 \left( \frac{\partial^2s}{\partial u \partial v}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial^2s}{\partial v^2}\right)^2 \right] du dv
$$

Now the question is **how do I get from this complex formula to a numerical method** (or say algorithm)? The papers I have seen (and I have read a lot) never mention this step. I does really not look obvious to me...

Comment: A guess $\ddot s$ is some measure for curvature or similar not so easily interpretable properties of the surface. In this sense you try to find a fitting curve which bends as less as possible.

Comment: Indeed! I have updated my initial post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In your equation, it's not even clear what $\ddot{s}$ means. But these "smoothing" terms are typically some heuristic measure of the "energy" required to bend the curve or surface. In other words, small values of this term make the geometry "smooth" in some vague sense.

Many sorts of smoothing terms are available, but they typically don't have a very good physical interpretation. Conversely, the expressions that make physical sense lead to nasty non-linear computations. There is a good discussion of this topic in [Henry Moreton's thesis](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1993/5219.html).

Perhaps the simplest approach is the so-called [thin plate spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_plate_spline). Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline#Multidimensional_splines).

Fortran source code for 1D spline smoothing can be found in the examples from Carl de Boor's book "A Practical Guide to Splines". Updated versions are available also on [his web site](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~deboor/). Presumably the algorithms can be extended to 2D (i.e. to surfaces), though I have never tried this.

Another good place to look for code is "The NURBS Book" by Piegl and Tiller. I don't know if it covers exactly the technique you're asking about, but it describes general techniques for least-squares fitting with NURBS surfaces, which might be adequate for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @bubba, I think your answer is relevant. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what Thin-Plate-Splines are.

I thought it was the name of a regularization technique for b-splines surface fitting (i.e. approximation smoothing, not exact interpolation). But reading papers, I understand they are a new type of splines (i.e. not b-splines), built out of the linear combination of RBF (Radial Basis Functions) - and potentially the addition of a plane, to smooth things off.

I am a bit lost here...

Comment: In my view of the world, a "thin plate" spline is any spline calculated by using the "energy" function given in the two references. You can use that energy function with radial basis functions, b-spline basis functions, or any other reasonable basis. If the radial basis stuff confuses you, just read the Wikipedia page about "smoothing splines" (the last reference in my answer). It doesn't mention radial basis functions.

Comment: Haha, this is interesting! Do you have any idea on **how to approximate the smoothing term as a quadratic cost**? So that the optimization problem remains linear?

Comment: Take a look at chapter 6 of Moreton's thesis. He approximates the integral by a quadrature formula, which presumably makes it as simple as possible. If you want to restrict your attention to linear problems, just try standard least-squares fitting. I think it's covered in the Piegl/Tiller book.

Comment: Will check Moreton, thanks @bubba!

Comment: I checked, and least squares fitting of surfaces (along with code) is covered in the Piegl/Tiller book.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at Piegl/Tiller and chapter 9.4.3 on surface fitting only proposes a very limited approach: they simply fit curves accross the data in one direction , then fit curves through the resulting control points accross the other direction. I guess this does not generalize very well to smoothing or more advanced techniques. I have also read Weiss (Advanced Surface Fitting Techniques) who gives an explanation both very simple and to the point. Currently reading Moreton. Thanks!